# Web Forms for Marketers Form Report Filters in Sitecore 8.1

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8, sitecore-mvc

I would like to add some custom filter on Web Forms for Marketers Form Report, is it possible?

For example: My contact page contains Name,Email,Phone Number,Request Type,Description.

In this page I would like to see the data filter by Request Type,Date.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Web Forms for Marketers Form Report is Sitecore SPEAK application. It means that you are able to customize and extend it using [SPEAK framework](https://doc.sitecore.net/speak/development). SPEAK is quite good extendable and you are able to customize any SPEAK application without any dirty tricks.

So, general answer is YES, it is possible.

However, I am not sure about efforts that you will need to do it. And will it enough for you to use only existing business components library, or you will need to create your own components.